# Can we put Jars in JMeter script as a package

Tags: java, jmeter, jmeter-5.0

Can we add jar file in script in package instead of lib folder.

Can we put Jars in JMeter script as a package directly instead of putting jars in JMeter lib. Is there any way to do??

Answer (score 0):

Please see the details on [Classpath Configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#classpath) for the utility jars.
You can place the jars in other locations than the lib folder. The location of the jar file need to be configured in user.properties file.

Answer (score 0):

You can add .jar files in 2 ways:

1. In [Test Plan](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Plan) there is "Add directory or jar to classpath" section:

   [image]
2. You can set `user.classpath` property to point it to the individual .jar files (or folders) containing your external libraries

More information:

- [JMeter's Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath)
- [How to Reuse Your JMeter Code with JAR Files and Save Time](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-reuse-your-jmeter-code-with-jar-files-and-save-time)